# Mark all the messages in a conversation as read

Tags: skypedeveloper

I'm using the Skype for Business Web SDK.  Is there an API call that I can make to mark all the messages in a conversation as read? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark a single message read by setting isRead to true.

conversation.historyService.activityItems is a collection of all messages from the conversation. Try looping through the collection and mark each message as read.

Check out this url for more info:
https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/05/learn-skype-web-sdk-day-15-receiving-instant-messages/

**Update April 2018:**

I have only recently started implementing this functionality myself and found out it's actually much easier thant that.
Simply call markAllAsRead() of the conversation' historyService --> conversation.historyService.markAllAsRead()